# What is the difference between Class.this and this in Java

Tags: java, this

There are two ways to reference the instance of a class within that class. For example:

```
class Person {
  String name;

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public void setName2(String name) {
    Person.this.name = name;
  }
}
```

One uses `this.name` to reference the object field, but the other uses `className.this` to reference the object field. What is the difference between these two references?

Answer (score 179, accepted):

In this case, they are the same. The `Class.this` syntax is useful when you have a non-static nested class that needs to refer to its outer class's instance.

```
class Person{
    String name;

    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    class Displayer {
        String getPersonName() { 
            return Person.this.name; 
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: If instead of Person.this.name you just said "return name" will that not work?

Comment: @Amit G - in this example, yes, it will work.  however, there are times when you need to clarify which "this" you are using (e.g. if there are conflicts in member var names or method names).  see Michael's answer for a relevant example.

Comment: One example would be when you have to give a reference to `Person.this` to another object.

Answer (score 88):

This syntax only becomes relevant when you have nested classes:

```
class Outer{
    String data = "Out!";

    public class Inner{
        String data = "In!";

        public String getOuterData(){
            return Outer.this.data; // will return "Out!"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14):

You only need to use className.this for inner classes. If you're not using them, don't worry about it.

Answer (score 4):

`Class.this` is useful to reference a not static `OuterClass`.

To instantiate a nonstatic `InnerClass`, you must first instantiate the `OuterClass`. Hence a nonstatic `InnerClass` will always have a reference of its `OuterClass` and all the
fields and methods of `OuterClass` is available to the `InnerClass`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        OuterClass outer_instance = new OuterClass();
        OuterClass.InnerClass inner_instance1 = outer_instance.new InnerClass();
        OuterClass.InnerClass inner_instance2 = outer_instance.new InnerClass();
        ...
}
```

In this example both `Innerclass` are instantiated from the same `Outerclass` hence they both have the same reference to the `Outerclass`.