# What does "SomeClass.this" mean in java?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between Class.this and this in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5666134/what-is-the-difference-between-class-this-and-this-in-java)

I know what `this` means in Java, but sometimes I see something like `SomeClass.this`, what does it mean? does it refer to a static class filed? Could you please explain with an example?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a way code in a method of your inner class can refer to the encompassing outer class instance.