# What's the difference between this and Activity.this

Tags: java, android, syntax, android-activity, this

For example

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
```

> eclipse  error: The method setClass(Context, Class) in the type
>   Intent is not applicable for the arguments (FirstActivity.ClickEvent,
>   Class)

```
Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
```

But that will be correct.
Anybody can explain the difference between those two ? 
Thanks.

Comment: Refer the following link might help you understanding your doubt.. [LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026973/android-whats-the-difference-between-the-various-methods-to-get-a-context)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

`this` refers to your current object. In your case you must have implemented the intent in an inner class ClickEvent, and thats what it points to.

`Activity.this` points to the instance of the Activity you are currently in.

Comment: does it affect performance, or make some other things that are in the background??

Answer (score 5):

Shubhayu's answer is correct, but I just want to make clear for anyone who see this question that `this` and `Activity.this` is the **same** if you are using it **directly in the activity**.

[This is answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5666134/what-is-the-difference-between-class-this-and-this-in-java)

Example:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    Log.d("Test", this.toString());
    Log.d("Test", MainActivity.this.toString());
}
```

Result:

```
D/Test: com.example.app.MainActivity@e923587
D/Test: com.example.app.MainActivity@e923587
```

Answer (score 2):

When you are pointing to this inside click event, it is pointing to the click listener.

Answer (score -1):

You are intent to transfer control from one activity to another and for that u ll have to specify an event basically and hence the error.
this means the entire activity and firstactivity.this means an event occurring for example a a button clicked.........