# Java syntax explanation

Tags: java, syntax

I'm new to Java and I encountered the following code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button = new Button(this);
        button.setText("Touch That!");

        button.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                MainActivity.this.onButtonClick(v);
            }
        });

        RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rootlayout);
        relativeLayout.addView(button);
    }

    public void onButtonClick(View view){
         //do something when button is clicked.
    }

}
```

I didn't understand the syntax, View.OnClickListener() c'tor is called and it is followed by **{}** and overidding method.
what does this syntax stand for?

to which object **this** refers?
My guess is the button. but if I'm right why to use **MainActivity.this** instead of **this**? (the object that invoked the method)

Comment: If you create only one MainActivity, you can even call `onButtonClick(v);`

Answer (score 3):

This is an anonymous class declaration. It means that you will override some methods inside the class dynamically.

Take a look at this arcticle:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html

About your second question, MainActivity.this refers to the instance of the Activity you are currently in. If you call only `this`, it would refer to the actual object. When you call `MainActivity.this`, you will get the instance of MainActivity you are in, even if there is more activities created. Take a look at Android's activity lifecycle.

[What's the difference between this and Activity.this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10102151/whats-the-difference-between-this-and-activity-this)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

By calling

```
new View.OnClickListener(){}
```

you are creating an object implementing interface OnClickListerner that requires you to implement the click method.

Someone can correct if I am wrong.