# java.lang.InstantiationException: class com.e has no zero argument constructor

Tags: android

I am getting this error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.e.www.i/com.e.www.i.Search}: java.lang.InstantiationException: class com.e.www.i.Search has no zero argument constructor
```

This is the below class :

```
public class Search extends Activity {
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView1;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter1;
    Context mContext;

    public Search(Context context) {

        mContext = context; // I guess the error is here, but I need to define context for below MyAdapter
    }
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_recycler_view);

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(
                new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
        mAdapter = new MyAdapter(getDataSet(),mContext);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

      }

private ArrayList<String> getDataSet() {
        ArrayList results = new ArrayList<DataObject>();
        for (int index = 0; index < 5; index++) {
            String obj = new String("User " + index);
            results.add(index, obj);
        }
        return results;
    }
```

Comment: try creating a zero argument constructor

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to define a **no-args** constructor, just as the error says:

```
public Search() {
    // No args constructor
}
```

The `context` that you need for your adapter is the `Activity` itself, you don't need to get it via the constructor. Just use `this`, since you are already in the context of an activity:

```
mAdapter = new MyAdapter(getDataSet(), this);
```

And then you can drop the **overloaded** constructor that you defined for your custom activity.

Comment: how to define the context to past it to myAdapter ?

Comment: ah .. I was doing it `(getDataset(), this.Search)` i though `this,search` is the same as `this`

Comment: euh... what ? you need to use `this` (or `Search.this`), not `this.Search`.

Comment: do you have link explain the difference between both ? I am still doing my first app , so many things I need to learn

Comment: **You need to use** `ClassName.this` to refer to the activity's context if you were working inside of an anonymous class (like from within a `View.OnClickListener` e.g, when handling a button click), because using `this` in this case would refere to the anonymous class, not to the container activity. Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10102151/whats-the-difference-between-this-and-activity-this

Answer (score 3):

In search, you created the constructor

```
public Search(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
}
```

Now, since you have a user defined constructor, your compiler does not provide you with any default constructors, so you need to define a parameter-less constructor yourself too.

```
public Search() {
    // Constructor body
}
```

Answer (score 2):

remove `Search(..) constructor` and just pass `conetext` to `adapter` like

```
 mAdapter = new MyAdapter(getDataSet(),Search.this);
```

As you are already in `Search Activity`

Answer (score 1):

If Argument is a must for example `IntentService`

```
public BaseIntentService() {
    super("IntentService");
}
```

Otherwise

```
public Search() {
    // Constructor body
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If any one is facing this problem with dependency injection. please add the annotation for activity . `@AndroidEntryPoint` . Also check if you added the required annotations for viewmodel/fragment/application etc.