# Cannot resolve method 'verifyPhoneNumber()'

Tags: java, android

My code is.

```
PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
                        phoneno,        // Phone number to verify
                        60,                 // Timeout duration
                        TimeUnit.SECONDS,   // Unit of timeout
                        this,               // Activity (for callback binding)
                        mCallbacks);        // OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
            }
        });
```

After writing callbacks it shows error like this

```
Cannot resolve method verifyPhoneNumber(android.widgit.EditText,int,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit,anonymous android.view.View.ONClickListener,come.google.firbase.auth.PhoneauthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks)
```

I have already defined mCallbacks. Can you please guide me with solution?

Comment: The java classpath in your error mentions `come.google.firbase.auth.PhoneauthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks`. I would expect that should be `com.google...` not `come.google...` Your code references `PhoneAuthProvider` (correct) but the error has different lowercase `PhoneauthProvider`. I also think you have the wrong scope of the package imported, don't you want this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/PhoneAuthProvider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass `phoneno.getText().toString()` as the first parameter.

For the second-last parameter, you are passing `this`, which refers to the anonymous inner class. You need to supply the reference of the containing activity class.

So change `this`
to `MyActivity.this`

(obviously replace "MyActivity" with your actual activity name)

Check [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/PhoneAuthProvider#public-method-summary) for all overloaded versions of `verifyPhoneNumber` method.

Also see [What's the difference between this and Activity.this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10102151/whats-the-difference-between-this-and-activity-this).

Answer (score 0):

As error message says you are passing edittext object instead of phone number -

```
verifyPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber, long timeout, TimeUnit unit, Activity activity, PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks callbacks)
```

as per method 1st param is string

try setting `phoneno.getText().toString()` -

```
PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
                    phoneno.getText(),        // Phone number to verify
                    60,                 // Timeout duration
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS,   // Unit of timeout
                    this,               // Activity (for callback binding)
                    mCallbacks);        // OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
        }**strong text**
    });
```

Comment: now it shows android.text.Editable, then I tried '''phoneno.getText().toString'''  and now it shows java.;ang.string

Comment: verifyPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber, long timeout, TimeUnit unit, Activity activity, PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks callbacks), 
Yeh you need to pass phoneNumber as string ,
second time unit that is correct, then Activity you should pass YourActivity.this then your callback.

thats it. It should work