# How to get reference to an anonymous object 2 levels up

Tags: java, gwt

I have code like this:

```
TextBox txt = new TextBox(){
  public void onLoad(){
    this.addFocusHandler(new FocusHandler(){
      //some codes here
      //if I use "this" keyword, it refers to the handler, but how can I get a reference to the textbox?
    });
  }
};
```

Question is embedded in the position.

---

**Edit:**

In respect to the answers, the creation of a pre-defined reference works for this situation, but this apparently lost (or at least reduce) the benefits of anonymous object/function.

I hope to find a way without creating a new reference. Rather just to get the reference from that scope.

---

After all the answers, here is a conclusion:

- Reflection does not work in GWT. (at least I did not succeed) `obj.getClass()` works, but others like `getMethods()` or `getEnclosingClass()` don't work.
- The way to get a reference can either be declaring a reference in the right scope, or get a higher level object reference and reference downwards. I prefer the latter simply because you don't need to create a new variable.

Comment: You probably shouldn't extend TextBox in this way just to addFocusHandler. If your concern is _readability_, then use an [anonymous code block](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563030/anonymous-code-blocks-in-java) or refactor into a method to construct the TextBox and add a focus handler to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has worked for me in the past. It works in client side js too. Here is a reference to more detail
[What is the difference between Class.this and this in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5666134/what-is-the-difference-between-class-this-and-this-in-java)

```
public class FOO {

    TextBox txt = new TextBox(){
          public void onLoad(){
            this.addFocusHandler(new FocusHandler(){

                @Override
                public void onFocus(FocusEvent event) {
                    FOO.this.txt.setHeight("100px");
                }
            });
          }
        };


}
```

Comment: Cool this works, but have to use upper level object reference. Anyhow this is the best answer :)

Answer (score 3):

```
TextBox txt = new TextBox(){
    public void onLoad(){
        final TextBox finalThis = this;
        this.addFocusHandler(new FocusHandler(){
             finalThis.doSomething();
        );
    }
};
```

Comment: This looks ok but it is not actually pointing to the right instance. I tried this methods and called a member function, but it cannot find that function.

Comment: First one is still not working. It gives error saying no instance of given class is in scope.

Comment: Yeah I saw some other examples with that method, but it seems like only be working when the outter class is not an anonymous class. I am assuming that if it is anonymous object hierarchy, it would not work.

Comment: Looks like this doesn't compile.

Comment: @johncart Yeap, FocusHandler needs a method. It is just an example, following the code from the question.

Answer (score 2):

The enclosing instance of a non-static inner class (anonymous or named) in Java is available as *ClassName*.this, i.e.

```
TextBox txt = new TextBox(){
  public void onLoad(){
    this.addFocusHandler(new FocusHandler(){
      doSomethingCleverWith(TextBox.this);
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: Doesn't work when that anonymous TextBox subclass is anonymous - that code doesn't compile.

Answer (score 0):

This may work for you:

```
TextBox txt = new TextBox(){
    public void onLoad(){
        final TextBox ref = this;
        this.addFocusHandler(new FocusHandler(){

            public void doSomething(){ 
                //some codes
                ref.execute();
            }
        });
    }
};
```

But I prefer to migrate inner classes to named classes:

```
public class Test {

    public void demo(){
        TextBox txt = new TextBox(){
            public void onLoad(){
                this.addFocusHandler(new DemoFocusHandler(this));
            }
        };
    }
}
```

External FocusHandler:

```
public class DemoFocusHandler extends FocusHandler {

    private TextBox textBox;

    public DemoFocusHandler(TextBox textBox){
        this.textBox = textBox;
    }

    public void doSomething(){ 
        //some codes
        textBox.execute();
    }
}
```

Comment: I've added an alternative way that may be considered more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

If gwt supported reflection you could do something along the lines of this:

```
final TextBox txt = new TextBox() {
   public void onLoad() {

      final Object finalThis  = this;

      this.addFocusHandler(new FocusHandler() {

         @Override
         public void onFocus(FocusEvent event) {
           try {
            Method method= finalThis.getClass().getMethod("getVisibleLength");
            method.invoke(finalThis);
           } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
           } 
        }
    });
  }
};
```

Without reflection the existing answers are you best bet. There are two gwt reflection projects [gwt reflection](http://gwtreflection.sourceforge.net/#overview) and [gwt-preprocessor](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-preprocessor/) both are in beta and I have not tried them.