# ClassName.this syntax but not for inner classes

Tags: java, jsp, taglib

When reading the [description](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/jsp/tagext/package-summary.html) for javax.servlet.jsp.tagext I came across a strange usage of the syntax `ClassName.this.methodName()` in the section **Generated Simple Tag Handler (MySimpleTag.java)**, specifically in the `MySimpleTag.doTag()` method.

```
public class MySimpleTag
    extends javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.SimpleTagSupport
[...]
{
    protected JspContext jspContext;
    public void setJspContext( JspContext ctx ) {
        super.setJspContext( ctx );
        // Step T.2 - A JspContext wrapper is created.
        // (Implementation of wrapper not shown).
        this.jspContext = new utils.JspContextWrapper( ctx );
    }
    public JspContext getJspContext() {
        // Step T.2 - Calling getJspContext() must return the 
        // wrapped JspContext.
        return this.jspContext;
    }

    public void doTag() throws JspException {
        java.lang.Object jspValue;
        JspContext jspContext = getJspContext();
        JspContext _jsp_parentContext = 
            SimpleTagSupport.this.getJspContext();
        [...]
    }
    [...]
}
```

I thought `ClassName.this` was only to be used within non-static inner classes that need access to the containing class instance.

- [What is the difference between Class.this and this in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5666134/what-is-the-difference-between-class-this-and-this-in-java)

And indeed, if I try to reproduce this in a simple example where a derived class calls a base class method with `BaseClass.this.someMethod()`, I get a compiler error:

```
error: not an enclosing class: BaseClass
    return Base.this.someMethod();
               ^
```

So does that mean the code for `MySimpleTag.doTag()` in the API documentation has a syntax error? Was the line actually supposed to be this?

```
JspContext _jsp_parentContext = 
            super.getJspContext();
```

Comment: It is a documentation bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @EJP points out, it's probably a documentation bug. The compile-time error makes it pretty clear the `ClassName.this` syntax is illegal outside of a non-static inner class.