# ListChangeListener.Change: how to properly handle updated and permutated items

Tags: javafx, changelistener

From the JavaDoc:

```
ObservableList theList = ...;

 theList.addListener(new ListChangeListener<Item>() {
     public void onChanged(Change<tem> c) {
         while (c.next()) {
             if (c.wasPermutated()) {
                     for (int i = c.getFrom(); i < c.getTo(); ++i) {
                          //permutate
                     }
                 } else if (c.wasUpdated()) {
                          //update item
                 } else {
                     for (Item remitem : c.getRemoved()) {
                         remitem.remove(Outer.this);
                     }
                     for (Item additem : c.getAddedSubList()) {
                         additem.add(Outer.this);
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
     });
 }
```

Adding and removing items is straight forward, but what about `//update item` and `// permutate`?

How do I know which items have been permutated by which other items?

What does update mean exactly? Is it just adding the same item to the list again?

And what about

```
for (Item remitem : c.getRemoved()) {
remitem.remove(Outer.this);
}
or (Item additem : c.getAddedSubList()) {
additem.add(Outer.this);
}
```

What does `Outer.this` mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How do I know which items have been permutated by which other items?

The change has a [getPermutation()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/ListChangeListener.Change.html#getPermutation--) method that describes how the elements were permuted.

---

> What does update mean exactly?

A list is updated if properties belonging to an element change, though the same elements remain in the list (in the same order). For example, given a class

```
public class Item {

    private final IntegerProperty value = new SimpleIntegerProperty();

    public final IntegerProperty valueProperty() {
        return value ;
    }

    public final int getValue() {
        return valueProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setValue(int value) {
        valueProperty().set(value);
    }

    public Item(int value) {
        setValue(value);
    }
}
```

calling `setValue()` on an element of the list may fire an update. Note that the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/ListChangeListener.Change.html#wasUpdated--) states that updates are "optional" and may not be fired by all lists. Specifically, to obtain a list that fires updates, create it with an [extractor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/FXCollections.html#observableArrayList-javafx.util.Callback-):

```
ObservableList<Item> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
    item -> new Observable[] {item.valueProperty()});

list.addAll(new Item(1), new Item(2), new Item(3));

list.addListener((Change<? extends Item> c) -> {
    while (c.next()) {
        if (c.wasUpdated()) {
            System.out.println("Items from "+c.getFrom()+" to "+c.getTo()+" changed");
        }
    }
});

list.get(1).setValue(42);
```

The last line of code doesn't change which elements are in the list, or which order they are in, but changes a property of one of the elements. So this change will fire an update.

---

> What does `Outer.this` mean?

It is simply a reference to the current object of the surrounding class (which is assumed to have class name `Outer`); i.e. not the current object of the anonymous inner class implementation of `ListChangeListener`. See [What is the difference between Class.this and this in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5666134/what-is-the-difference-between-class-this-and-this-in-java) (and many others). I think the context for the code snippet in the documentation is supposed to be a class that implements `ObservableList` and maintains its own `ObservableList` instance (decorator pattern). It observes the list instance and updates itself to keep in sync with it.

Comment: Many thanks for the explanations! One more question regarding Outer.this.
Should the code not be `Outer.this.remove(remitem)` and `Outer.this.add(additem)` intead?

Comment: I guess in my interpretation the code you suggest would be more intuitive. Perhaps the idea is that the surrounding class (`Outer`) is some kind of listener, and the code is registering/deregistering the listener to items that are added and removed. Not exactly sure what the intention was in the documentation.